# Is my motherboard compatible with an Intel i7?

Tags: laptop, cpu, intel-core-i7, processor-socket

I have an IBM ThinkPad Z61t with an Intel Centrino Duo. I want to know if it's possible to upgrade to one of Intel's i7 processors.

I understand that there's different pin structures for different processors so not all are compatible, but I don't know that much about them, and Google isn't very helpful.

Comment: Laptops are too proprietary for things like CPU upgrades. Also by looking at the age of your laptop, upgrading to an i7 CPU would not be possible or even worth it based on your hardware limitations. A few specs I pulled from the same laptop for sale on Amazon `2 GHz - Centrino Duo - RAM 1 GB - HDD 100 GB `. You're better off buying a new one that is upgraded to what you want.

Comment: If you can find the specific model of your CPU you could determine the socket type, and then google will help you find all CPUs that are compatible with that socket. However, what @DrZoo said still stands: Many laptops will not allow you to modify or replace the chip. Especially such a big jump as between a Centrino Duo and an i7, the newer chip will probably require more cooling capability than your laptop has.

Comment: "I want to know if its possible to upgrade to one of Intel's i7 processors." - Which one specifically?  The "Centrino Duo" has a specific socket, only processors with that same socket, has any chance of being compatiable with your laptop.  Of course the fact the CPU in question, is soldered onto the motherboard, removing it would require specific tools and soldering skills to acomplish.  I am voting to close this question because you are not specific enough.

Comment: I disagree Ramhound. It may not be a particularly good question, but it has an answer: No. None of the i7 processors will work with that mainboard. You don't need to know a specific model if you already know there aren't any that will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: No.

The two sockets possibly used in this laptop are the 478 and 479, both of which only supported Celeron, Pentium 4, and Centrino processors from the mid-2000's.

The Core line of processors did not in any form ever work with either of these sockets.

Also, this computer is around 10 years old today, and the value from upgrading it will be absolutely minimal considering current software needs and the maximum possible hardware you could install in it.

It is a better value to replace this computer complete if you need modern processing power in any form.

Comment: Also worth noting that if it's using the PBGA479 package, then the processor will be soldered to the motherboard... so not exactly '_user replacable_'